# Ruby: What does unpack("C") actually do?

Tags: ruby, pack

From the docs, `unpack` does:

> Decodes str (which may contain binary data) according to the format
>   string, returning an array of each value extracted.

And the `"C"` format means `8-bit unsigned (unsigned char)`.

But what does this actually end up doing to the string I input? What does the result mean, and if I had to do it by hand, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 7):

It converts each subsequent char to it’s integer ordinal as [`String#ord`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-ord) does. That said,

```
string.unpack 'C*'
```

is an exact equivalent of

```
string.each_char.map(&:ord)
```

Answer (score 5):

> But what does this actually end up doing to the string I input

It doesn't do anything to the input. And the input is not really a string here. It's typed as a string, but it is really a buffer of binary data, such as you might receive by networking, and your goal is to extract that data into an array of integers. Example:

```
s = "\01\00\02\03"
arr = s.unpack("C*")
p(arr) # [1,0,2,3]
```

That "string" would be meaningless as a string of *text*, but it is quite viable as a data buffer. Unpacking it allows you examine the data.

Comment: I can’t understand why this is downvoted, so I have it upvoted for the sake of common sense.